# Why does select on unbound/unconnected sockets not fail?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select

Here is my example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    printf("--> fd is %d, FD_SETSIZE is %d\n", fd, FD_SETSIZE);
    fd_set set;
    FD_ZERO(&set);
    FD_SET(fd, &set);
    int retval = select(fd + 1, &set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if(-1 == retval)
    {
        perror("select");
    }
    printf("retval is %d\n", retval);
}
```

Why does select not fail or block/timeout? (`retval` is 1, and `fd` is set in set) But on an an openend socket, there is no data availible. Is there anything in the documentation i missed?

Comment: Possibly related to the problem, but I doubt it: You pass the wrong value for the first argument of `select`. It should be the highest descriptor plus one. In your case `fd + 1`.

Comment: Same mistakes as in [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47098097/694576): Wrong include, wrong nfds!

Comment: More related to your problem, what *is* `select` returning? What is the output of the program you show? What output did you expect?

Comment: If `select` indicates that a file descriptor is "ready", that does not necessarily mean there is data to read or space to write. It just means that the read or write operation won't block.

Comment: @alk Again, this does not matter.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude I added your suggestions to the question

Comment: @IanAbbott This might be the clue here. A following `read` actually does not block but fail.

Comment: ... although my "won't block" is the wrong phrase, since the descriptor might be non-blocking. What it really means is that the descriptor has something to report. For the "read" set, the thing to report could be "data available" or "read will error". For the "write" set, the thing to report could be "space available" or "write will error".

Comment: I just did the same thing on winsock2. There it blocks :(